# Live mp3 stream playing by Media Player without buffering

Tags: android, audio, stream, mp3, media-player

My question is about media player live streaming from the url in my application?

I'm trying to play **live stream mp3 audio by media player**.

The problem is that when i am using default `URL` as given in this [link](http://androidstreamingtut.blogspot.in/2012/08/custom-progressive-audio-streaming-with.html) , then it works fine. But i changed the following mp3 [link](https://ia600502.us.archive.org/12/items/Mp3Songs_175/actionreplayy04www.songs.pk.mp3) , 
then after playing 1 seconds it taking buffering and after completion its play the song, but **i need that it plays the song with the buffering** as well.

please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy task to accomplish.
You can use this link https://code.google.com/p/mp3tunes/source/browse/

as reference app to develop your own progressive mediaplayer app.
From the above link you will get the whole architecture for your app.Song downloading and playing is happens at the same time.The architecture developed in the reference app is more robust and reusable.
Specially look at following classes

- NanoHTTD.java
- HttpServer.java
- PlaybackService.java
- PlaybackQueue.java
- TrackDownloader.java

Thank You.

Comment: i have download the code , but it had too much errors.. and i am not able to edit..

Comment: You can resolve the compile time errors and can run it. of course it will take time.

Comment: yes ashwin , i had try to resolve the compile time errors but these are reverting back , after correction ...

Comment: add on skype , if its possible , if you can do help   : deepak.kumar3038

Comment: I have done this with ffmpeg, stream is running and recording simultaneously in sd card..hppy

Comment: can you please post your steps (of ffmpeg) as answer to this question so that it will help others.

Comment: yes, ashwin i can tell the steps, and can share codes also

Comment: im using vitamio, to play RTSP stream and recording the frames to sd card